# List definition by repeated entry/iteration

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I want to define the [Thue-Morse Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) (or the [fair-sharing sequence](https://youtu.be/prh72BLNjIk)) in terms of an initial element, `0`, and the rule defining the next section of the list in terms of the entire list up until this point. i.e.

```
fair 0 = [0]
--fair 1 = [0,1]
--fair 2 = [0,1,1,0]
--fair 3 = [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
fair n = fair (n - 1) ++ map (1-) (fair (n - 1))
```

This works fine to generate the list up to any predefined length, but it seems ineffective to not just define the entire list at once, and use `take` if I need a predefined amount.

My first attempt at defining the entire list was `fair = 0 : map (1-) fair` but of course, this populates the list as it goes, so it doesn't ever (need to) reenter the list (and returns `[0,1,0,1,0,1...]`). What I want is some way to define the list so that when it reaches a not-yet-defined element in the list, it defines the next 'chunk' by reentering the list **only until that point**, (rather than the computation 'chasing' the new values as they're produced), so the steps in computing the list would be akin to this procedure:

- begin with initial list, `[0]`
- map `(1-)` over the existing list, producing `[1]`
- append this to the existing list, producing `[0,1]`
- map `(1-)` over the existing list, producing `[1,0]`
- append this to the existing list, producing `[0,1,1,0]`
- map `(1-)` over the existing list, producing `[1,0,0,1]`
- append this to the existing list, producing `[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]`

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) I linked above has a [helpful gif](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Morse-Thue_sequence.gif) to illustrate this process.

As I presume you can see, this would continue indefinitely as new elements are needed. However, I can't for the life of me find a way to successfully encode this in a recursive function.

I have tried

```
reenter f xs = reenter f (xs ++ map f xs)
fair = reenter (1-) [0]
```

But while the logic seems correct, it hangs without producing anything, probably due to the immediate recursive call (though I thought haskell's lazy evaluation might take care of that, despite it being a rather complex case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, you can't do the recursive call immediately - you first need to return the next result, and then recursively call, as in your last try:

```
Prelude> reenter prev_list = inverted_prev_list ++ reenter (prev_list ++ inverted_prev_list) where inverted_prev_list = map (1-) prev_list
Prelude> f = [0] ++ reenter [0]
Prelude> take 20 f
[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is code in Racket, another functional programming language, using the steps listed in the question.

```
(define (f n)

  (define (invert s) ; sub-function to invert the numbers
    (list->string
     (for/list ((i (string->list s)))
       (if (equal? i #\0) #\1 #\0))))

  (let loop ((c 1)
             (s "0")) ; starting string is "0"
    (if (> c n)
        s
        (loop (add1 c)
              (string-append s (invert s))))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 1)
(f 2)
(f 3)
(f 4)
(f 5)
```

Output:

```
"01"
"0110"
"01101001"
"0110100110010110"
"01101001100101101001011001101001"
```

For infinite series:

```
(define (f)
  (define (invert s)
    (list->string
     (for/list ((i (string->list s)))
       (if (equal? i #\0) #\1 #\0))))

  (let loop ((s "0"))
    (define ss (string-append s (invert s)))
    (println ss)
    (loop ss)))
```

To run:

```
(f)
```

This may give some ideas regarding a Haskell solution to this problem.